# How can I detect errors in an HTML document fragment with Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I'm collecting some HTML formatted content from a web form. Before saving this HTML content, I'd like to do a quick sanity check on it to make sure it looks well-formed (no unclosed tags, no invalid markup).

Using Ruby and/or with any popular gems, can I check an HTML fragment string like:

```
<p>foo</p><h1>Unclosed H1<p>bar</p>
```

and discover things like the unclosed `h1` tag?

I thought Nokogiri would come to my rescue here, but no:

```
>> Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse("<p>foo</p><h1>Unclosed H1<p>bar</p>").errors
=> []
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`w3c_validators`](http://code.dunae.ca/w3c_validators/)?

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'w3c_validators'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> include W3CValidators
=> Object
[3] pry(main)> p MarkupValidator.new.validate_text('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><p>foo</p><h1>Unclosed H1<p>bar</p></body></html>');
```

This gives you very detailed validation result.

Or maybe if you want to just check closing tags, maybe `Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse().errors` instead, but this probably doesn't work unless doctype is XHTML since a few HTML elements in other doctype don't require even closing tag so. `w3c_validators` does better

Comment: The w3c_validators gem appears to wrap the W3C's online validation service.  I'd like a solution that doesn't require network connectivity.  I'll try injecting my HTML fragment into an HTML doc with an XHTML doctype to see if Nokogiri will catch the unclosed tags then...