# How to get Nokogiri to report or raise error on invalid Html fragment?I

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

It seems Nokogiri doesn't honor it's strict option.

```
html = %Q{<ul id="Test"><li></ul></li>}
parsed = Nokogiri::HTML(html) do |config|
  config.strict
end
```

This should raise an error according to documentation:
http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html

```
STRICT - Strict parsing; raise an error when parsing malformed documents
```

Code they are using to turn on options is this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("blossom.xml")) do |config|
  config.strict.noblanks
end
```

There was a similar question before, but no answer:
[How can I detect errors in an HTML document fragment with Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661517/how-can-i-detect-errors-in-an-html-document-fragment-with-ruby)

Answer (score 2):

Typically I use [`errors`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Document#errors-instance_method) to find out what's wrong:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<ul id="Test"><li></ul></li>')
doc.errors # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Unexpected end tag : li>]
```

You'll see the same when parsing as a DocumentFragment:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse('<ul id="Test"><li></ul></li>')
doc.errors # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Unexpected end tag : li>]
```

It returns the same for:

```
parsed = Nokogiri::HTML('<ul id="Test"><li></ul></li>') do |config|
  config.strict
end
parsed.errors # => [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: Unexpected end tag : li>]
```